# What is better: reusing System.Data.Linq.DataContext context or disposing of it ASAP?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

If I am using a SqlConnection, apparently the best practice is to dispose of it ASAP, and let the connection pooling handle the details. Should I follow the same pattern when I am using System.Data.Linq.DataContext?

Should I create my context once and pass it along to my methods, or should I get the connection string from my config file and create the contexts multiple times and save on passing the parameters?

**Edit:** A useful link about identity maps: [Architecting LINQ To SQL Applications, part 7](http://codebetter.com/iancooper/2008/03/09/architecting-linq-to-sql-applications-part-7/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep a data context around only as long as necessary to perform an operation.

The reason for this is that it uses something called an Identity Map so that every time you select say customer 1 you get the same object back. This means it is holding lots of references and will consume more and more memory over time and these results will become increasingly stale.

In the case of a web app it is common to create one per request and the DataContext class is optimised for quick creation.

Comment: +1 It's important to note that the definition of "operation" is (unfortunately but necessarily) pretty much left up to the developer; for practical purposes, an "operation" may take some time and require significant user interaction in the case of a rich client like WinForms or WPF.

Comment: I personally wouldn't let a users interaction delays be involved in the lifecycle of a data context but going such a route does involve a lot of extra work.

Comment: If the user is in the middle of editing a record, I'm not sure that the benefits of doing that are clear-cut; even if you were to materialize different contexts for retrieval and save operations, you still have to deal with stale data. Only now you've essentially lost the tracking that the context gives you unless you move to something like STE, which has its own headaches and isn't nearly as robust.